# How is 眷顾 used in spoken Chinese?

Tags: usage, spoken

I've encountered 眷顾 on several occasions but I am not sure how to distinguish it from 照顾 in terms of usage. I have seen an example sentence of 上帝眷顾我们的事业, so is 眷顾 usually used with God and deities?

Comment: some users suggest looking at the 100 samples in jukuu for each of 照顾 and 眷顾 (7-100 almost exclusively religious, mainly bible translations)

Comment: 眷顾 is abstract and cannot be verified/proven.

Answer (score 1):

> [眷](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/8549/)
>
> (1) family dependent
>
> (2) care for, have tender feeling for, take interest in

~

> [顧](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/3635/)
>
> (2) [v] look after; attend to

~

> [眷顧](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/53127/)
>
> (divine) protection and care; to take care of

Both 眷顧 and 照顾 mean "to take care of/ to look after". But 眷 carries the meaning of 'family dependent' therefore 眷顧 also carries the meaning of " to take care of someone **like family dependent**" or " to protect and care for someone **like family dependent**"

- You can 照顾 a garden, but you cannot 眷顧 it.
- When you say you 照顾家人, that means you look after your family. ( with or without emotional attachment)
- When you say you 眷顾家人, that means you love, protect and look after your family dependent.(with emotional attachment)
- 神的眷顾 = God's protection and care (All man are God's children)

Answer (score 1):

眷顾 can be considered as the English word "bless"(verb) or "blessing" (noun), relevant to God and deities. well, 照顾 is normal word meaning "take care of".

Answer (score 0):

上天眷顾 Favorable Destiny
照顾[zhào gu]
1.（考虑到; 注意到） give consideration to; show consideration for; take account of; make allowance(s) for:
make allowance for the majority; think in terms of the majority; 照顾多数
be careful of one's respectability; 照顾面子
2.（关心; 照料） look after; care for; attend to:
look after the wounded 照顾伤员